# Built in keyboard that supports all Mongolian characters

Tags: macos, keyboard

While OS X supports a vast library of characters in its set of keyboards, Mongolian is missing.  I would like to know if Mac OS (Yosemite) has a keyboard with a character set sufficient to type all Mongolian characters.  If possible, I would prefer a keyboard that most resembles traditional Mongolian keyboards.  Installing keyboard apps or extensions would be a last resort.

Comment: Mongolian QWERTY layout can be found here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46870715/k/MongolianQWERTY.keylayout.zip and the Cyrillic here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/46870715/k/MongolianQWERTY.keylayout.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Apple has never provided a Mongolian keyboard layout with OS X (either cyrillic or traditional script).  You will have to use one of layouts which can be downloaded and installed from the internet.  Another example is

http://mountainedge.netfirms.com/store/page3.html